# NodeJS Server on Windows Not Accepting Remote Connections

Tags: windows, node.js

I'm running a simple web app on a NodeJS server running on port 8080 of a Windows machine. Local connections are working great, but I can't seem to get remote connections working. I've looked around for answers to this question, and I'm kind of at a loss...

The server is listening with `server.listen(8080)`, and I'm under the impression that will bind it to all IP addresses.

I checked the Windows command prompt...

```
netstat -an -f -p tcp | grep LISTEN
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

And I added an inbound rule to my Windows Firewall to accept TCP connections on port 8080. What else could it be?

When I navigate Chrome to localhost:8080, things work great, but when I ssh into a Linux box and curl to http://{mypc}:8080 it tells me `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

EDIT: I'm using this script to start my Node server...
https://github.com/joeeames/AngularFundamentalsFiles/blob/master/web-server.js

Comment: Is this Windows machine your development one? Is it behind something (say, a router) with its own firewall?

Comment: I don't think so, because I have gotten remote connections working with an IIS web app running on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@minitech was right. A firewall above me allows port 80 connections, but not port 8080. Changing the Node server to start on port 80 solved the problem.